# How to Debug basic kubernetes image pull failure

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am trying to learn how to deploy my application to Kubernetes, and am using the local docker desktop kubernetes instance.  I have built my container image and have run a script that generates a deployment file for me.  Essentially when I manually deploy it works but when I use a deployment.yml file it fails and I am at a loss as to understand why this is the case and diagnose what is wrong.

I've clearly missed something basic but how can I work out what the difference is between the commands and why it is failing?

When I run this command to apply the deployment yaml:

```
kubectl apply -f .\deployment.yml
```

The pod fails to start without being able to pull the image, but when I run what I think is the same command with a manual deployment like this:

```
kubectl create deployment manual-test3 --image=rts.api:1.0.0.1
```

It seems to work fine, so far the best logs I can find are using this command - the output for the manual deployment is here:

```
kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=manual-test3-87dbcbf66-dp7zt
LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON      OBJECT                             MESSAGE
42s         Normal   Scheduled   pod/manual-test3-87dbcbf66-dp7zt   Successfully assigned default/manual-test3-87dbcbf66-dp7zt to docker-desktop
37s         Normal   Pulled      pod/manual-test3-87dbcbf66-dp7zt   Container image "rts.api:1.0.0.1" already present on machine
35s         Normal   Created     pod/manual-test3-87dbcbf66-dp7zt   Created container rts-api-7xrfz
34s         Normal   Started     pod/manual-test3-87dbcbf66-dp7zt   Started container rts-api-7xrfz
```

Running the same command for the failing deployment clearly states that it cant log in to get the image.  However as this is all local I'm not sure what I would log in with ( docker desktop is logged in) and as far as I can tell it should be the same as the working manual deployment.

```
kubectl get events --field-selector involvedObject.name=rts-api-76759d7d7b-67ctg
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON      OBJECT                         MESSAGE
2m51s       Normal    Scheduled   pod/rts-api-76759d7d7b-67ctg   Successfully assigned default/rts-api-76759d7d7b-67ctg to docker-desktop
70s         Normal    Pulling     pod/rts-api-76759d7d7b-67ctg   Pulling image "rts.api:1.0.0.1"
68s         Warning   Failed      pod/rts-api-76759d7d7b-67ctg   Failed to pull image "rts.api:1.0.0.1": Error response from daemon: pull access denied for rts.api, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
68s         Warning   Failed      pod/rts-api-76759d7d7b-67ctg   Error: ErrImagePull
46s         Normal    BackOff     pod/rts-api-76759d7d7b-67ctg   Back-off pulling image "rts.api:1.0.0.1"
58s         Warning   Failed      pod/rts-api-76759d7d7b-67ctg   Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

The deployment.yml file is here, but as far as I can tell it should be identical to the manual deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rts-api    
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rts-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rts-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rts-api
        image: rts.api:1.0.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Thank you for any help / insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Essentially when I manually deploy it works but when I use a
> deployment.yml file it fails

That's because you specified

`imagePullPolicy: Always` in your deployment.

If you check [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy):

**Always**

*every time the kubelet launches a container, the kubelet queries the container image registry to resolve the name to an image digest. If the kubelet has a container image with that exact digest cached locally, the kubelet uses its cached image; otherwise, the kubelet pulls the image with the resolved digest, and uses that image to launch the container.*

Since there is not container registry, it can't check image digest.

Change policy to `IfNotPresent` or `Never`

Comment: THANK YOU! so much! I have been stuck on this for ages.  To help my understanding is this because it is not actually using an image registry - but using the local docker instance as a cache?  I was assuming that the local docker instance was a registry from which it should Always pull but it sounds as if it is not a container registry at all?

Comment: it depends on your CRI backed, it could be containerd, or something else. docker itself is not a registry